# BarLegend with two different scales (ticks&labels)

Tags: plotting, legending

I am looking for a way to plot e.g. a legended `DensityPlot` with a `BarLegend`, where the colorbar shows two differently scaled ticks and labels. Take the following example:

[image]

or take a look at the folloowing example from Python/matplotlib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151098/draw-colorbar-with-twin-scales.

Idealy I would like to provide a scaling relation to to apply to the data values in order to get the second scale.

I was hoping that there is already some hidden functionality in place, But I couldn't coerce `"Charting'TickSide"`  to allow for other arguments than `Left` or `Right`. After some fiddling around I could at least convince Mathematica to plot two `BarLegends` and hacked `Column` for a partial overlap (the -2 spacing argument).  I also tried to fiddle around with the `InputForm` but the `BarLegend` is not converted to `Graphics` primitives. But that is as far as I got.

```
Legended[
 MatrixPlot[
   Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}],
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][Rescale[#, {1, 100}]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
 Placed[
   Column[{
     BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {1, 100}}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
       Charting`TickSide -> Left, 
       LegendLabel -> "\[Degree]F", 
       LegendLayout -> "Row"],
     BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {1, 100}}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
       Charting`TickSide -> Right, 
       LegendLabel -> Placed["\[Degree]C", Below], 
       LegendLayout -> "Row"]}, 
   Automatic, -2], 
   Below]
]
```

[image]

Interesting remark: the quotation marks aropund the °C in the lower `LegendLabel` ("°C") only appear in the jpg, not on the screen in the notebook ouotput.

Comment: Before I dig into this let me ask: what is the reason that you do not draw the legend entirely manually?  I ask because I would not want to work on a solution only to find that it did not avoid the same thing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was hoping that the 'new' PlotLegends functionality would allow for some easy implementation (given the huge number of undocumented Charting`* functions. I also will need to combine this plot with others I already did using PlotLegends and I would like to keep the same style.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a functional solution to make a general 2-scale legend.

```
Options[twoScaleLegend] = {"LegendOrientation" -> "Horizontal"};
twoScaleLegend[{xmin_, xmax_}, {label1_, label2_}, scale2_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{twoScaleLegend, DensityPlot}]] :=

 Module[{ticks, aspectratio, framelabel, ticklength},
  ticklength = 
   If[OptionValue["LegendOrientation"] === "Vertical", .2, .01];
  framelabel = {{None, None}, {label1, label2}};
  If[OptionValue["LegendOrientation"] === "Vertical", 
   framelabel = Reverse@framelabel];
  aspectratio = 
   If[OptionValue["LegendOrientation"] === "Vertical", 20, 1/20];
  ticks = {{None, None},
    {Function[{min, max}, {#, N@#, ticklength {1, 1}} & /@ 
       FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5] ],
     Function[{min, 
       max}, {InverseFunction[scale2]@#, N@#, ticklength {1, 1}} & /@ 
       FindDivisions[scale2 /@ {min, max}, 5] ]}};
  If[OptionValue["LegendOrientation"] === "Vertical", 
   ticks = Reverse@ticks];
  DensityPlot[
   If[OptionValue["LegendOrientation"] === "Vertical", y, x],
   {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, xmin, xmax},
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DensityPlot]]],
   AspectRatio -> aspectratio,
   PlotRangePadding -> None,
   FrameTicks -> ticks,
   FrameLabel -> framelabel,
   RotateLabel -> False]
  ]
```

It's a little bit clunky, I couldn't figure out how to get the tick mark length to be the same in either vertical or horizontal orientation.  Here are two examples of how it would be used,

```
twoScaleLegend[{0, 100}, {"°C", "°F"}, (1.8 # + 32 &),
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]
twoScaleLegend[{0, 100}, {"°C", "°F"}, (1.8 # + 32 &),
  "LegendOrientation" -> "Vertical", BaseStyle -> 15]
```

[image]

And here it is with your matrix plot,

```
{Legended[
  MatrixPlot[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][
       Rescale[#, {1, 100}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Placed[
   twoScaleLegend[{0, 100}, {"°C", 
     "°F"}, (1.8 # + 32 &), ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]
   , Below]],
 Legended[
  MatrixPlot[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][
       Rescale[#, {1, 100}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Placed[
   twoScaleLegend[{0, 100}, {"°C", 
     "°F"}, (1.8 # + 32 &), ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
    "LegendOrientation" -> "Vertical"]
   , Right]]}
```

[image]

Comment: That's neat. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that is not general but working for me at the moment. Since I was looking for a simple linear scaling I just applied it to the range argument `1.8*{1, 100} + 32` in `BarLegend`

```
Legended[
 MatrixPlot[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][Rescale[#, {1, 100}]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   Placed[
     Column[{
       BarLegend[{"SolarColors", 1.8*{1, 100} + 32}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 300, Charting`TickSide -> Left, 
         LegendLabel -> "\[Degree]F", LegendLayout -> "Row"],
       BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {1, 100}}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 300, Charting`TickSide -> Right, 
         LegendLabel -> Placed["\[Degree]C", Below], 
         LegendLayout -> "Row"]
             }, Automatic, -2], 
     Below]]
```

[image]

The length of the two `BarLegends` does not match because of the placement of the ticks. One quick hack is to provide other limits, e.g. `{1,99}`

```
Legended[
 MatrixPlot[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][Rescale[#, {1, 99}]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   Placed[
     Column[{
       BarLegend[{"SolarColors", 1.8*{1, 99} + 32}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 300, Charting`TickSide -> Left, 
         LegendLabel -> "\[Degree]F", LegendLayout -> "Row"],
       BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {1, 99}}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 300, Charting`TickSide -> Right, 
         LegendLabel -> Placed["\[Degree]C", Below], 
         LegendLayout -> "Row"]
             }, Automatic, -2], 
     Below]]
```

[image]

I am still interested in a more general and less ugly solution.